# javascript pass control id to postback function does't work

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback

I am trying to do a manual postback in ASP.NET with time delay and came up with the following line:

```
setTimeout("__doPostBack(" + senderId.id.toString() + ", ' ')", 600);
```

There is some problem with it as it doesn't execute. Could please someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var str = senderId.id.toString();
setTimeout(function() {
    __doPostBack(str);
}, 600)
```